# insert category from form in a post

Tags: wp-insert-post

when the category comes from a form, how I can use in wp_insert_post?

```
$my_post = array(); 
$my_post['post_author'] = $userid; 
$my_post['post_title'] = $name; 
$my_post['post_name'] = str_replace(' ', '-', $name); 
$my_post['post_category'] = $selected = $_POST['postcats']; 
$newpost_id= wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

is it correct? what is it wrong?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the category first, then add it to the post:

```
$my_post = array(); 
$my_post['post_author'] = $userid; 
$my_post['post_title'] = $name; 
$my_post['post_name'] = str_replace(' ', '-', $name);
$cat_id = wp_create_category($_POST['postcats'], 0); // we create the category and we get the ID, the 0 is for no parent category
$my_post['post_category'] = array($cat_id);//this value is an array not a single value 
$newpost_id= wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

you can also just create the post and add the category later with [wp_set_post_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories)

Comment: It doens't work This is the rror: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_create_category() in ... inc/custom-abc.php on line 31

Comment: The line is this: $cat_id = wp_create_category($_POST['postcats']); // we create the category and we get the ID, the 0 is for no parent category I gave the list of category (this is a custom type)

Comment: this is my function:

Comment: function create_post_from_user($email, $name, $address, $city, $country, $phone, $subcategory, $userid, $mobile)
{
    global $post,$wpdb,$tag;
    $directory_url_1=get_option('_iv_directory_url_1');     
    if($directory_url_1==""){$directory_url_1='azienda';} 
    $directory_url_2=get_option('_iv_directory_url_2');     
    if($directory_url_2==""){$directory_url_2='professionisti';}

Comment: $query = "SELECT tt.term_id, taxonomy, parent FROM $wpdb->terms AS t INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id WHERE t.slug='" . $subcategory .
            "' AND taxonomy in ('" .$directory_url_2.'-category' ."','".$directory_url_1.'-category'."')";
    $taxonomy_term = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
    $parentCategoryId=$taxonomy_term[0]->parent;
   $my_post = array(); 
$my_post['post_author'] = $userid; 
$my_post['post_title'] = $name; 
$my_post['post_name'] = str_replace(' ', '-', $name);
$newpost_id= wp_insert_post( $my_post );

Comment: $post_type='';
    if($taxonomy_term[0]->taxonomy == $directory_url_1.'-category')
    {
        $post_type=$directory_url_1;
    }
    else if($taxonomy_term[0]->taxonomy == $directory_url_2.'-category')
    {
        $post_type=$directory_url_2;
    }
    if($post_type!=''){
        $query = "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts SET post_type='" . $post_type . "' WHERE id='" . $newpost_id . "' LIMIT 1";
        $wpdb->query($query);          
    }

Comment: are `get_option` and `wp_insert_post` working?? its this function added to a hook? its in functions.php? by the way you should edit your question with this code.

Comment: Tthis complete function is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256083/wp-insert-post-custom-type it's a file, it's included in a paypal file payment when the form is sent, Thanks